# Docker для разворачивания WordPress

Tags: wordpress, docker, url

Пробую разобраться в разворачивание докер контейнера для работы с `Wordpress`
тестовый проект называется `http://crecker.loc`
Мой `docker-compose.yml` имеет вид

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  # WordPress service
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_HOME', 'http://cracker.loc');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://cracker.loc');
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    depends_on:
      - db

  # MySQL service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  # phpMyAdmin service
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
```

Почему-то при прописании данного адреса в поисковой строке браузера вылетает с ошибкой.
`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Что делаю не так, в чём ошибка ?

Добавлю работающий вариант докер файла, для сравнения.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  # WordPress service
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    depends_on:
      - db

  # MySQL service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  # phpMyAdmin service
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
```

Проблема в том, что необходимо что б вместо `http://localhost:8000/` было название проекта в качестве `url` адреса. Возможно, кто-то сможет на своем PC запустить этот докер, и показать как сделать так что б подставлялась замена урла?

Comment: Вы, же прописали домен `crecker.loc` в hosts файл на локальной машине?

Comment: эммм, нет. А как это делать ? Куда писать ? у меня Windows 10/

Comment: дополнил свой ответ, посмотрите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно прописать локальный домен `crecker.loc` в `hosts` файл.

Фйл расположен:

- Windows 7-11 — c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts;
- Linux, Unix, BSD — /etc/hosts;
- MacOS — /private/etc/hosts.

Формат такой:

```sh
# <IP> <Domain>

127.0.0.1 crecker.loc
```

---

## UPD к вашему дополнению вопроса

Пара слов вначале:

1. Возможно, вам стоит продолжить использовать `OSP` или `MAMP`. `Docker` это, всё же, другой продукт, для других задач.
2. В вашем конфиге вы неправильно описали биндинг порта 80. У вас `- "80"` а должно быть `- "80:80"`
3. Использовать 80 порт (который как раз не нужно писать в домене - это стандартный порт http) для всех ваших контейнеров не получится. На одном порту одновременно может "висеть" только одно приложение.
4. Я, пока, не встречал людей, которых парит что надо писать `localhost:1234`. **Обычно это не вызывает проблем**.
5. Чтобы сам Wordpress работал корректно с указанием порта, в конфиге docker-compose нужно ему указать корректный URL с портом (если порт не `80` или не `443`) `define('WP_HOME', 'http://<HOST>:<PORT>');` и `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://<HOST>:<PORT>');`
6. В домене вместо `.loc` лучше использовать `.localhost`. У меня в Linux, это избавляет от необходимости менять `hosts` файл. Правда не уверен будет ли это работать в Windows. Мне кажется, что за это отвечает не ОС, а сам браузер, но тут я не очень уверен.

---

Если же очень хочется реализовать, то что вы хотите средствами Docker, тогда придется потанцевать, немного, с бубном:

### Traefik

Первым делом вам понадобится маршрутизатор (т.н. `edge router` или `reverse proxi`), который будет перенаправлять запросы в нужные контейнеры. Для этого можно использовать `Traefik`. [Документация Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/)

Нужно создать контейнер Traefik'а, который будет принимать всё что приходит на 80 порт localhost'а и перенаправлять запросы куда нужно. Удобство Traefik в том, что настройки маршрутов делаются не в конфиге Traefik, а в свойствах непосредственно контейнера.

Создайте папку где будете хранить конфиг траефика и в ней файл `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Поднимаем reverse-proxy. Опция `-d` запустит контейнер Traefik в фоне.

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

Для проверки, что Traefik заработал, переходим по адресу http://traefik.localhost

### Конфиги сервисов

Дальше идем в папку с проектом. В `docker-compose.yaml` нужно сделать несколько правок:

#### 1. Port binding

Из конфигов сервисов, которые будут работать через Traefik, убираем настройки `port:`. Они на м не понадобятся.

#### 2. Добавляем метки для Traefik

Для того чтобы Traefik смог настроить маршрутизацию, нужно к контейнеру добавить соответствующие метки:

```yaml
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.<C-NAME>.rule=Host(`<HOST>`)
      - traefik.http.services.<C-NAME>.loadbalancer.server.port=<C-PORT>
```

Здесь:

- `<C-NAME>` - имя контейнера
- `<HOST>` - хост по которому будет доступен контейнер (в вашем случае - cracker.localhost)
- `<C-PORT>` - порт контейнера. Зависит от используемого образа. В случае `wordpress` - это порт `80`.

Повторяем то-же самое, только с другим хостом для сервиса `phpmyadmin`.

#### 3. Помещаем все в сеть Traefik'а

Добавляем следующий конфиг в самый низ файла `docker-compose.yaml` приложения.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    name: traefik_default
```

Вот такой конфиг получился в итоге у меня:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  # WordPress service
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.wordpress.rule=Host(`cracker.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.services.wordpress.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_HOME', 'http://cracker.localhost');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://cracker.localhost');
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    depends_on:
      - db

  # MySQL service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  # phpMyAdmin service
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`phpmyadmin.cracker.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.services.phpmyadmin.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password


networks:
  default:
    name: traefik_default
```

Поднимаем приложение.

```bash
docker-compose up
```

Через пару-тройку секунд после запуска сайт должен стать доступен по адресу http://cracker.localhost, а PHPMyAdmin по адресу http://phpmyadmin.cracker.localhost

## UDP 2

В зависимости от того, как вы называли папки, в которые складывали конфиги, сеть в которой будет работать Traefik может отличаться от нужно (нужно чтобы сеть называлась `traefik_default`).

Чтобы этого избежать, нужно в конфиг Traefik добавить сеть. Получиться что-то такое:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro



networks:
  default:
    name: traefik_default
```

Чтобы применились настройки, в папке с конфигом Traefik нужно выполнить команду:

```bash
docker-compose restart
```

Для того чтобы убедиться, что Traefik и наше приложение работают в одной сети нужно выполнить команду:

```bash
# traefik_default - это имя сети в моих примерах
 docker network inspect traefik_default
```

В результате должна выдаться информация о сети в которой будет список работающих в ней контейнеров:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik_default",
...
...
...
        "Containers": {
            "6e859c46087e823b5ea72697e540326e4a6369e4b664aeb638eddef971e75e4a": {
                "Name": "test-phpmyadmin-1",
                "EndpointID": "1f0286629d44c6b36b0996c170cf149f0cf2e7812ce4e0edb00c6f63e896ac75",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "aea8fd1ffc101b06a3d3d653bbf1b758adb33e94c2b6ce77bfda33d5fd4b5f5a": {
                "Name": "test-db-1",
...
...
            },
            "d7f7aadbe76d9a4fd40b5ad7113f88cd7568a7f4dd11af9d1dd14ce282e1699d": {
                "Name": "test-wordpress-1",
...
...
            },
            "e9d365cc9904abeb913eb32f7706bb50008656ee38de4edb5674c7f6ec078d7f": {
                "Name": "test-reverse-proxy-1",
...
...
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
...
...
...
    }
]
```

Comment: Это не помогло.  Прописывая в адресной строке браузера `crecker.loc` меня бросает теперь на гугл выдачу, а не созданный локальный сервер

Comment: @BlackStar1991 это потому что ты не правильно прописал.  А ответ верный.

Comment: @SeVlad Что конкретно не правильно прописано ? Можно детализацию получить ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 , все верно. Браузер не знает такой корневой домен (`.loc`), поэтому кидает на выдачу. Нужно писать адрес с протоколом: `http://crecker.loc`

Comment: всё равно не отрабатывает. хоть с указанием домена, хоть без

Comment: @RAMe0 протокол не нужно указывать. В ответе ты всё правильно написал.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 отсюда не видно ни где ни что никак ты делаешь. Но в гуглояндексах полно информации как нужно делать.

Comment: Я видимо не очень хорошо сформулировал. В файле `hosts` НЕ нужно писать протокол. Его унжно писать в _адресной строке браузера_ :) Неоднократно сталкивался с тем, что браузеры не понимали что за рандомный корневой домен я пишу и отправляли на поиск.

Comment: @RAMe0 Я прекрасно понял, что не в файле `host` Но, всё таки оно не стартует... Думал, что адрес за кэшировался и проблема в браузере, но - нет. В других браузерах оно тоже не отрабатывает.  Возможно что-то в стоках `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://crecker.loc' );
        define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://crecker.loc' );` не так задаю... ? Оно обновляет, но не отрабатывает

Comment: @BlackStar1991, без данных об ошибке вообще сложно что-то сказать. Если все еще открывается поисковик при вводе адреса, то дело в браузере. Нужно выбрать чтобы открылся сайт, а не поиск. Если дело уже в другом, то дополните вопрос информацией об ошибке. Так же, проверьте запущены ли вообще контейнеры и посмотрите их логи. В Windows это легко можно сделать через Docker Desktop. И, если будет непонятно что за ошибка, дополните свой вопрос.

Comment: Да, еще уточнение, вы же открываете сайт `http://crecker.loc:8000`? Просто у вас в конфике указано, что контейнер WP "открывает" во вне порт `8000`, для доступа к порту `80` контейнера  (`- "8000:80"`)

Comment: нет, просто `http://crecker.loc` писал. Просто хочу что б оно работало... как в OpenServer как в MAMP. Почему тут так всё сложно... http://crecker.loc:8000 тоже не отрабатывает.

Comment: Так ‘crecker.loc’ или ‘cracker.loc’  всё же? У вас в коде одно, а прописываете другое.

Comment: Сделал всё по инструкции, сменил в hosts на `127.0.0.1 cracker.localhost` Оно не стартует. Пишет сообщение -  Для перенаправления запросов локального IP-адреса к нужному вам локальному домену создайте алиас в настройках программы.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, кто именно и где такое пишет?

Comment: У вас случаем OpenServer или что-то еще, что висит на порту 80 не запущено?

Comment: Да, действительно. Ошибку показывало из-за включенного OpenServer. Теперь когда выключил и перезагрузил. По адресу выдает ошибку - `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`   При этом если запустить команду `docker-compose exec wordpress curl http://localhost` html страницу в консоли оно показывает

Comment: @BlackStar1991, `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED `, скорее всего, означает то, что Traefik у вас не запущен. Если бы он работал, то выдавал бы другого вида ошибки.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ еще одним важным нюансом: траефик и ваше приложени должны быть в одной сети.

Comment: Запрос по траефику выдает следующее http://joxi.ru/Y2LGOgyuvea19m , но всё равно не стартует, и возвращает с ошибкой `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: 1) на вашем скрине `docker network inspect traefik_default` не видно списка контейнеров работающих в этой сети. В данном случае нам это важно; 2) Вы так и не написали работает ли у вас траефик вообще. Посмотрите в Docker Desktop в разделе Containers у контейнера траефика должен быть статус `running`. Если он отличается, надо смотреть логи и еще попытаться запустить из консоли без флага `-d` чтобы увидеть какие-то возможные ошибки

Comment: Спасибо, дошло. Забыл активировать для второго образа из директории traefik  `docker-compose up` Когда оба запустил, оно отработало.